# preg_match_all -> string: var a = 100

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying parse string:

```
var a = 100
var b = 150
var c = test
```

I was trying create regex:

```
preg_match_all('/var( )*=( )*([^\s]+)/', $code, $get_zmienne);
preg_match_all('/var(\s)*=(\s)*([^\s]+)/', $code, $get_zmienne);
```

and this is wrong.

Comment: What is wrong? What you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I need get "a" and "100" as array. I have to use regex - not explode

Comment: `/var\s+(\w+)\s+=\s+(\w+)/`

Comment: Sammitch - it works. One beer for you ;) Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a try with:

```
preg_match_all('/var\s*(\w+)=\s*(\S+)/', $code, $get_zmienne);
```

This will match:
`var`:  litteral `var`
`\s*`: 0 or more white spaces
`=`: litteral `=`
`(\w+)`: group1 that contains one or more word characters ie:`[a-zA-Z0-9_]`
`\S+`: one or more non space character.